# Deserializing tuples with argument in Rust

Tags: api, rust, tuples, deserialization

I am a beginner in rust and working with some api that returns bytes that I can deserialize by defining their types.

```
result: (f64, f64, f64) = api.call();
```

Can I do the same by dynamically by passing a value n for the number of elements?

All elements of the tuple are of the same type. I would like to do something like this:

```
result: tuple(f64, 3) = api.call();
```

[Here](https://docs.rs/ethers-contract/0.5.3/ethers_contract/struct.Multicall.html#method.call) is the API of the call function.

**Edit**:
In case anyone ever encounters that issue in the future. I could deserialize the output by adopting [this solution](https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/pull/915/files#diff-f7ed5ca95548046c8f53e9acec04d1412a8e5db4cece5f3500be57c7a8067359R523-R539).

Comment: There's no such thing as a tuple defined by its length. In Rust, the equivalent are [arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html). What's the actual signature for the `call` function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is the function I am calling https://docs.rs/ethers-contract/0.5.3/ethers_contract/struct.Multicall.html#method.call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference: `call()` returns a `Result<D: Detokenize, _>`. [`Detokenize`](https://docs.rs/ethers-core/0.17.0/ethers_core/abi/trait.Detokenize.html) is mainly implemented for all `T` that implement [`Tokenizable`](https://docs.rs/ethers-core/0.17.0/ethers_core/abi/trait.Tokenizable.html).

All types that can receive the result are listed [here](https://docs.rs/ethers-core/0.17.0/ethers_core/abi/trait.Tokenizable.html#foreign-impls).

Note that additional to tuples of various size, it's also implemented for:

```
impl<T: TokenizableItem + Clone, const N: usize> Tokenizable for [T; N]
```

Further, note that it is an `async` function with a `Result`, meaning you have to `await` it and deal with the potential error.

So you should(tm) be able to write:

```
result: [f64; 3] = api.call().await.unwrap();
```

Of course in a real project I would advise to replace `unwrap()` with some proper error handling.

Disclaimer: I don't know how to use the rest of `ethers-core`, so I'm unable to verify this in a test project. This information is purely derived from the documentation.

---

### Static vs dynamic size

`[f64; 3]` requires you to know the number of elements at compile time.

Note that another `Tokenizable` is `Vec<T>`, meaning you could also  specify `Vec<T>` as a result type. The length of this one will then be resolved at runtime, depending on how many elements of `T` the `api.call()` returns.

---

### Further background information

Note that there is no such thing as a tuple that has N number of T elements, because a tuple is not a repetition of one type, it's a collection of types. Every element of a tuple can have a different type.

If you want to represent a repetition of one type, an [array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) is what you really want. It's defined as one type T repeated N times: `[T; N]`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. I receive the following error message when trying
it out:
 
`thread main panicked at called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: ContractError(DetokenizationError(InvalidOutputType("Expected FixedArray(15), got Tuple` That seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/gakonst/ethers-rs/issues/41